# Take string value in where clause - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've created a simple mysql table like [this](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6lsK0AZGV54/UoG5UyVXtSI/AAAAAAAAAXE/ZTpiIjZPYJA/w556-h125-no/table.jpg)

models column takes VARCHAR(30)

But when I execute this query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `Vehicle_Duty_Chart`
 WHERE models = "SE3P"
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It returns this

```
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 sec)
```

What ever the 'models' column value I give result is the same. For queries like

```
 WHERE  ins =7000
```

returns desired outputs. 
I've no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: what does `where models like 'SE3P%'` return?

Comment: same output. "empty result set "

Comment: try using TRIM around "models" column to check if it contains white space.

Comment: Sunny using TRIM it gives desired outputs. It's whitespace problem I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Vehicle_Duty_Chart`
WHERE TRIM(models) = "SE3P"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: "SE3P" contains white space before or after it causing the problem. TRIM() removes the trailing and following white spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicle_Duty_Chart WHERE models LIKE  '%SE3P%' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some unwanted whitespace in your models field, you may want to trim it off for all records. Be sure you are ok losing leading and trailing whitespace on all your Vehicle_Duty_Chart models.

```
UPDATE `Vehicle_Duty_Chart` SET `models` = TRIM(`models`);
```

After this, your string comparison queries should work without needing to call trim for every query.

If models column contains more than one value separated by a comma or some other delimiter, you might want to change the query to something more like Nikul's answer.